# is it possible to execute jquery in the returned results of a previously executed jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a selection box that makes use of `jquery $.post()` on the change to parse the data in php and returns the results through `postit.done()` and renders it in a specified div. This works fine.

The problem is in the returned parsed results there is a class for a tool tip that is suppose to respond on the hover but does not.

**This is the code for the selection box:**

```
# selector wrap
    # ------------------------------------------------
    echo '<div class="selector-wrap row">';
        echo '<div class="col_12">';
        echo '<label>Available Classes</label><br>';
        echo '<select id="classCat" name="classCat" class="expand">';
            echo '<option value="0">Select Classes Category</option>';

                /* loop though classes data files categories to populate options */
                foreach(glob($level.'css/classes/data/*.dat') as $file) {
                    $id = $file;
                    $title = basename(str_replace("-"," ",str_replace(".dat","",$id)));

                    echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.ucwords($title).'</option>';
                }

        echo '</select>';       
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';

    # render desired content
    # ------------------------------------------------
    echo '<div class="showClasses renderQuery"></div>';
```

**Here is the jQuery:**

```
/* parse get special caracters category */
    $("#classCat").change(function(){
        var id = $(this).val();
        var url = siteURL + 'css/classes/parse-class-categories.php';
        var postit = $.post( url, {id:id});     
        postit.done(function( data ) {$('.showClasses').html(data);});      
    });
```

**And this is the parsing php file:**

```
<?php   
    /* get content for this category */
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $content = file_get_contents($id);
    $cleanit = substr($content, -1); if($cleanit == ','){$content = substr($content, 0, -1);}

    /* if no cat selected */
    if(empty($id)){echo '';}    

    /* render selected category */
    elseif(!empty($id)){        

        echo '<div class="slideContnetWrap clearfix">'; 

            /* loop through this category and render classes */
            $getClasses = explode("\r",$content);
            foreach($getClasses as $getClass){

                $pcs = explode("|",$getClass); $this_class = $pcs[0]; $about = $pcs[1];

                echo '<div class="col_12">';

                    echo '<div class="rendered-label" style="font-size: 12px;">';
                        echo '<span class="tooltip-left" title="'.$about.'"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> </span>';         
                        echo ' <span class="renderHead">'.ucwords(str_replace("-"," ",$this_class)).'</span>';
                    echo '</div>';

                    echo '<div class="getItInput">';
                        echo '<input type"text" class="expand" ';
                        echo 'onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length);" value="'.$this_class.'">';
                    echo '</div>';

                echo '</div>';              
            }           
        echo '</div>';
    }
?>
```

This line in the php parse file is suppose to render a tool tip when hovered but does not... it works otherwise in other areas.

```
echo '<span class="tooltip-left" title="'.$about.'"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> </span>';
```

I am self-taught and not fully up to speed on how the DOM works... Is this because the parsing file is not loaded during the initial load and is called by jquery itself after the page has been loaded? And if so is there a work around for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would generally be considered as code-injection, and would not be executed by any modern browser.

Bring the rendering/event logic back into JQuery and use the PHP to provide the data upon request instead.  As long as you use the browser's Javascript engine for your rendering and event handling, then all will be well.

Comment: Thanks @Steve Harris for responding... I get the code injection... I kind of thought it was something to that effect. I am not quite sure what you mean in the your solution... how would I bring the rendering/event logic back into jquery... can you expound

Comment: You are returning dynamic snippets of HTML from your PHP.  Instead return JSON or some other other data, and use that to render the dynamic snippets using JQuery/Javascript.   You can construct HTML elements in JQuery easily and add them to your DOM.  You can also use CSS and JQuery methods to hide/show elements and just render all the HTML you will ever need, but just hide the parts you aren't using.  There are lots of ways to work through the problem without rendering HTML on the server side.   In fact, with things like React and AngularJS you can go almost wholly browser side with bindings.

Comment: Thank you @Steve Harris... I understand what you are saying.